# How to get rid from spam MySQL insert?

Tags: php, spam

I really wonder that how someone adding records to my existing blog comment table. I am using my own custom blog script where user add comment on any particular blog. I have a separate comment table with blog id. I have tried several CAPTCHA technique but nothing works. I am using PDO for mysql. I am also doing JavaScript validation before submitting the form. I am not sure if he/she is real people or some bots are doing that. Within 1 hour thousands of records being added.

I am posing my code below. Can someone help me please?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user_comment']))
{

if ($_SESSION['answer'] == $_POST['answer'] ) 
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$web = $website;
$comment = addslashes(nl2br($_POST['comment_text']));
$comment =strip_tags($comment);
$id = $article_id;
$ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
$userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$submit_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if ((($name) && ($email) && ($comment))) {

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database",$username,$password);


$sql = "INSERT INTO blog_comments (user,email,website,message,date,storyid,userip,useragent,block) VALUES (:user,:email,:website,:message,:date,:storyid,:userip,:useragent,:block)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':user'=>$name, ':email'=>$email, ':website'=>$website, ':message'=>$title, ':date'=>$submit_date, ':storyid'=>$id, ':userip'=>$userip, ':useragent'=>$useragent,':block'=>'1'));

        }

}
else
{
?>
<tr><td>
<p style="text-align:center; color:#CC0000; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:10px;">Wrong Answer! Please try again!!</p>
</td>
</tr>           

<?php
}
}
?>
```

THIS IS MY CAPTCHA CODE:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $digit1 = mt_rand(1,20);
    $digit2 = mt_rand(1,20);
    if( mt_rand(0,1) === 1 ) {
            $math = "$digit1 + $digit2";
            $_SESSION['answer'] = $digit1 + $digit2;
    } else {
            $math = "$digit1 - $digit2";
            $_SESSION['answer'] = $digit1 - $digit2;
    }

    ?>
```

THIS IS JS VALIDATION:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function validate()
{
        if( document.getElementById( "name" ).value == ""){
           alert("Please enter your name.");
           document.getElementById( "name" ).focus();
           return false;
        }
        if( document.getElementById( "email" ).value == ""){
           alert("Please enter Your email ID.");
           document.getElementById( "email" ).focus();
           return false;
        }
        if( document.getElementById( "comment_text" ).value == ""){
           alert("Please enter your comment.");
           document.getElementById( "comment_text" ).focus();
           return false;
        }

        if( document.getElementById( "answer" ).value == ""){
           alert("Please solve this math.");
           document.getElementById("answer").focus();
           return false;
        }
}
</script>
```

THIS IS MY FORM:

```
<form action="" method="POST" onSubmit="return validate();">
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%">
<tr><td colspan="3">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? print($id);?>">
</td></tr>

<tr>
<td style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; width:150px;">Your Name</td>
<td style="width:260px;"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" style="width:250px; height:20px;"></td>
<td style="text-align:left;">Required</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; width:150px;">Your E-mail</td>
<td style="width:260px;"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" style="width:250px; height:20px;"></td>
<td style="text-align:left;">Required</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; width:150px;">Your Website</td>
<td style="width:260px;"><input type="text" name="website" style="width:250px; height:20px;"></td>
<td style="text-align:left;">Optional</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; width:150px;">Your Comment</td>
<td style="width:260px;"><textarea name="comment_text" id="comment_text" style="width:250px; height:100px;"></textarea></td>
<td style="text-align:left;">Required</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; width:150px;">What's <?php echo $math; ?> = </td>
<td style="width:260px;"><input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" style="width:250px; height:20px;"></td>
<td style="text-align:left;">Required</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" name="user_comment">
</td></tr>


</table>

</form>
```

Comment: Maybe someone posted one and kept hitting F5? You should at least add a redirect so that can't happen anymore. Can you show your Captcha and JS validation as well?

Comment: JS validation is useless to counter that, bots send request directly to your PHP script. Are you sure your captcha is working right ?

Comment: No! All comments are new with different IPs. I am also using captcha and javascript validation. So if someone just resubmit the form then he/she will get wrong captcha error.

Comment: Yes, my captcha is working fine. There is no problem with Captcha.

Comment: try to look at the IPs, are there comments from the same ip? if there are only a few numbers of IP, but they repeat, then you could block this IPs

Comment: @NeerajKumar Where is php validation, in case javascript is turned off?

Comment: @user4035 Not using PHP validation. But I think that is not big issue because I am am validating the captcha before submit.

Comment: and what is with SQL-Injection if you dont use PHP validation?

Comment: @NeerajKumar I see it here: `($_SESSION['answer'] == $_POST['answer'] ) `. Can you show your form HTML code?

Comment: @user4035 I have added the html code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I have found the solution myself. Now I am showing the last commented date time instead of CAPTCHA and asking user to input that value as it is in input box. All captcha techniques failed whereas this technique works perfectly and i am not getting spam any more.

Thanks you so much to all you experts for giving your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to select from db previous record of a user with posted email and compare the content or the date with posted data. If the content is the same or date range is very small, than show approving message for posting or do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your Captcha is not very safe. Any Bot can give you the answere.

```
What's <?php echo $math; ?> =
```

This will only shown as Text `What's x + y =` answer is z.

Every Bot and every self written Javascript can fill all requireds fields and get the "question" and fill it in the answer field.

And i guess that if you hit F5 in your browser after you post a comment, the php script will also save it in your DB, because the answer in your session is not deleted after one try.

Try to print an image with the question instead of a text and delete the answer in your Session after first try.
This should solve the problem.

Comment: Earlier I have tried it with image captcha but that didn't work.

Comment: How i said your php code does not any validation, it does not delete the answere. You only need a proxy switcher and a bot and you have lots of comments in a short time.

Comment: I have added a new field in my table to capture the math answer and surprised that they have answered like a human e.g. 12, 8, -3. So are they real people inserting comment through website. But how could they enter hundreds of comments in short time with different ips and useragent.

Comment: why only humans can do this? any bot can do this, too. I could write a bot that could do this easily in 10 minutes. Because it is always the same structure (always math operations with - and +)